# Taffy API framework Patch verb not working in lucee

Tags: api, coldfusion, lucee, taffy

I've created a taffy API endpoint in patch verb

I would run the explore to throw the below error

Patch verb working stable in ACF but not working in lucee

> MY lucee version -> Lucee 4.5.4.017 final

Any one let me know how to fix that issue

[image]

Mycode:

```
<cfcomponent extends="taffy.core.resource" taffy_uri="/artist/">

    <cfset variables.dummyData = StructNew() />
    <cfset variables.dummyData.whatever = true />
    <cfset variables.dummyData.phone = encode.string(5558675309) />
    <cfset variables.dummyData.phoneNumeric = 5558675309 />

    <cffunction name="patch" access="public" output="false">
        <cfreturn representationOf(variables.dummyData).withStatus(200) />
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: Update the code in my post check and let me know